# Copy documents from one collection to another in MongoDB via Java API

Tags: java, mongodb

I have two collections, 'recruits' and 'items'.  I gather documents in 'recruits', perform some calculations, and want to move the documents that meet my criteria to the 'items' collection.  I know that in the shell, I could use db.cloneCollection(), passing in my query as a parameter.  However, I need to do this programmatically, from the Java API.  I cannot use the $out operator for aggregation, as I need to insert into the collection, not replace it.  I'm not psyched about using map-reduce, as the times I've tried to use it in the past, it doesn't behave as I expect.

Is there a better option than iterating over the result of my find() and inserting the documents?   Can anyone explain why cloneCollection() is not available in the Java API?

Thank you!

Comment: Why a -1?  If you think my question is bad, please tell me why so I can improve it.
I did research - the other questions all pointed to using JavaScript or aggregation, neither of which is applicable to my situation.

Comment: Clone collection is not available through the driver as it will not work if you're connecting to a sharded instance of MongoDB.  As @alernerdev says, you can run it as a command, but this should not be done if you're working in a sharded environment.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with the Java driver, but I am sure it can send arbitrary dbCommands?  If so, cloneCollection is a dbCommand -- did you try that?

Comment: I did not.  It wound up making the most sense to just drop the 'recruits' collection and re-gather the data that matched the original criteria, inserting into the 'items' collection.